# VueJS: remove listener setup in view

Tags: vue.js

My code:

```
<input type="text" v-on:keydown="handler">
```

How can I manually destroy this listener ? I can do this:

```
handler: function(){
  return;
}
```

But I want to completely remove listener itself. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Is `$off()` what you are looking for?

> Remove event listener(s).
>
> - If no arguments are provided, remove all event listeners;
> - If only the event is provided, remove all listeners for that event;

http://vuejs.org/api/#vm-off

Comment: it isn't because `off` removes only custom event listeners